# Row summation of convergent double sequence is eventually finite

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Given a double sequence $\{a_{n,m}\}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n,m}=0$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$. Is that true that there is some large $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $\sum_{m=1}^\infty |a_{n,m}|<\infty$?

If we also know that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}a_{n,m}=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, does the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^\infty |a_{n,m}|$ exist?

I appreciate any help on proofs or counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double sequence $a_{n,m}=\frac{1}{nm}$ is a counterexample.